# Prove $n$ is even and $\text{rank}(AB)^{k}=n/2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n\geq2$ be an integer and $A, B$ two $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries, such that $A^{2}=B^{2}=0$, with $A+B$ being invertible. Prove that $n$ is even and $\text{rank}(AB)^{k}=n/2,$ for all $k\geq2.$

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, here is a proof that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(B) = \frac n2$, which incidentally proves that $n$ is even.

If $\operatorname{rank}(A)=r$, then there exist $r$ independent vectors $\{Av_1, Av_2, \dots, Av_r\}$. We know $A^2v_1 = A^2v_2 = \dots = A^2v_r = 0$, because $A^2=0$, so all $r$ of these vectors are in the null space of $A$, and we have $\dim \operatorname{Null}(A) \ge r$. Therefore we have $$2r \le r + \dim \operatorname{Null}(A) = n \implies r \le \frac n2$$ by applying the rank-nullity theorem. Similarly, we get $\operatorname{rank}(B) \le \frac n2$.

To prove the reverse inequality, note that $\operatorname{rank}(A+B) \le \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$ (this is true for any two matrices $A$ and $B$). But $A+B$ is invertible, so it has rank $n$. Therefore
$$n = \operatorname{rank}(A+B) \le \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \le \operatorname{rank}(A) + \frac n2 \implies \operatorname{rank}(A) \ge \frac n2$$ and we get $\operatorname{rank}(B) \ge \frac n2$ in the same way.

---

The proof that $\operatorname{rank}((AB)^k) = \frac n2$ follows more or less the same logic.

To get the upper bound, that $\operatorname{rank}((AB)^k) \le \frac n2$, suppose that $\operatorname{rank}((AB)^k) = r$ and there are $r$ independent vectors $\{(AB)^k w_1, (AB)^k w_2, \dots, (AB)^k w_r\}$. Once again, all of these are in the null space of $A$ (since if you multiply by $A$ on the left, the product begins with $A^2$), so there can be at most $\frac n2$ of them. Similarly, $\operatorname{rank}((BA)^k) \le \frac n2$: we'll need this, too.

Inductively, we can show that for all $k\ge 1$, $$(A+B)^{2k} = (AB)^k + (BA)^k.$$ When $k=1$, we have $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + AB + BA + B^2$, and $A^2=B^2=0$ so those terms cancel. To go from $k$ to $k+1$: 
\begin{align}
(A+B)^{2(k+1)} &= (A+B)^2 ((AB)^k + (BA)^k) \\
 &= (AB + BA)((AB)^k + (BA))^k \\
 &= (AB)^{k+1} + AB(BA)^k + BA(AB)^k + (BA)^{k+1} \\
 &= (AB)^{k+1} + (BA)^{k+1}
\end{align}
where the $BA(AB)^k$ and $AB(BA)^k$ terms cancel due to having an $A^2$ or $B^2$ factor.

Since $\operatorname{rank}(A+B)=n$, we have $\operatorname{rank}((A+B)^k) = n$ for all $k$, so 
$$n = \operatorname{rank}((AB)^k + (BA)^k) \le \operatorname{rank}((AB)^k) + \operatorname{rank}((BA)^k)$$
and, as before, since both ranks on the right are at most $\frac n2$, the inequality can only hold if both are exactly $\frac n2$.

Comment: Can you please prove that the rank of ( AB )^kis n/2?

Comment: I can, but you should try to do it yourself first, both because it's good for you and because I'm on my way home and can't do it for the next while anyway. The reasoning's really not that different, and writing the proof yourself will help you understand it.

Comment: I can't use the same metod.  I don't see how

Comment: Okay, here it is.

Comment: Can it be proved that (AB)^2=0?

Comment: It can't be $0$, because $\operatorname{rank}((AB)^2) = \frac n2$, and $\operatorname{rank}(0)  = 0$.

Comment: The result was never to prove that $(AB)^2=0$, though. Which part of the (updated) proof are you confused about?

Comment: It's in the answer above; I updated it.

Comment: No, because that's false.